# usage of language model file while creating a dictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I created a speech to text recognition app.For that purpose i developed a dictionary using CMULanguage tool.For creating the dictionary for my project,i added two files to my Language folder present in Groups and Files.The files are having extensions .lm(language model) and .dic.

These files are being supplied to me by the CMULanguage tool when i uploaded my Corpus.I want to know that what is the usage of this .lm file?anyone if know please let me know about this topic.

Thanks in advance,
Christy

Comment: Please help me with this --anyone

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary and the language model are two separate items -- you can not convert one into the other, and you can't just delete / not provide one of them -- both are needed!

The dictionary is used to tell the search algorithm what the valid words are and how they relate to phonemes / the phonetic transcription.

The language model is used during the recognition of an utterance, by using the probability of a uni-gram, bi-gram, n-gram .. when the search algorithm is considering a word-transition.