# Usage of Language model file in dictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [usage of language model file while creating a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731248/usage-of-language-model-file-while-creating-a-dictionary)

I created a dictionary with my set of words using CMULanguage tool for my app Speech recognition.I then added two files which are provided to me by the CMULanguge tool to my project.

The files are - .lm file i.e language model file and other is .dic file.

Can anyone tell ,me what is the usage of this language model file.

i tried to create the app by removing the languagemodel file from my project.The app build successfully but when i deployed it in Ipad then the app crashed within no time.With ths i came to know that language model file is necessary while creating dictionary but i dont know what is the real usage of this file.I searched it at many places but havent got anything ye.Now i think that no one knows about this thing.So please anyone prove me wrong please.

Christy

Answer (score 0):

you use the probability of the language model when considering the "cost" of a word-transition in the search.
:-)  but that's probably not what you wanted to hear.

The dictionary and the language model are two separate items -- you can not convert one into the other, and you can't just delete / not provide one of them -- both are needed!

The dictionary is used to tell the search algorithm what the valid words are and how they relate to phonemes / the phonetic transcription.

The language model is used during the recognition of an utterance, by using the probability of a uni-gram, bi-gram, n-gram .. when the search algorithm is considering a word-transition.